# Safe to run a 1/2 watt resistor at 0.4 watts in enclosed housing?

Tags: resistors, cooling

I have a circuit that dissipates 0.4 watts through a 1/2 watt resistor. It gets quite hot to the touch. Every other component in the system is cool. I am just trying to make sure this is safe in a circuit in a closed box with minimal venting.

Comment: My own rule of thumb....  If you can't touch it and hold your finger on it, it's too hot.   Are you technically too hot?  no.  Can the resistor handle it?  Probably.  How important is it that your device not fail?   And how much does a 1W resistor cost???

Comment: So it is in open air at the moment and you propose to reduce the cooling by enclosing in a box… what do you think?

Comment: Quite likely OK. MAY not be
 If 'quite likely wont die' is good enough reliability it may be ok. Or not. I usually derate resistors by 50,% . If it matters you can probably use a datasheet and some estimate of enclosure thermal resistance .

Comment: Use a resistor explicitly designed for several W.

Comment: IIRC the resistors are rated to 75°C. It also depends on how much the resistor is running continuously. If it's 100% duty I'd use at least a 1W part

Comment: Here some interesting specifications, specially about Time Life specs : https://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/RC0603.pdf 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27358019_Model_for_Reliability_Prediction_of_Thick_Film_Resistors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You should never choose resistors** to operate > 50% of rated power for THT parts to allow for ambient rise above 25'C.  Using 100% rated power at 25'C means the resistor is operating at 125'C and heating up nearby components or a 100'C rise.  Using 50% of Pmax means the internal temp will rise 50'C above the surrounding enclosed ambient.  For SMT resistors with some thermal conduction to PCB, suppliers often raise ceramic body limits to 155'C. but this also reduces MTBF.

- using 80% of rated power in an enclosed space is one example to avoid unless you operate in a continuous air conditioned room and there is some conduction cooling in the enclosure and not a plastic box.  This means the body temperature will rise 80'C above ambient air around it. If the air cannot exit, from convection,  its temperature will also rise.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a reputed make resitor, it will not fail unless the ambient temperature of the resistor goes very high. I have seen some low cost resistors where rated wattage is 3W and they smell and getty pretty hot anything above 2W.

An engineer would check the temperature of resistor in actual application (enclosed) and see how much headroom is available in the datasheet temperature specifications. You can too do that if you have/can buy a multimeter with thermocouple input.

Other safe way would be to use a higher wattage rated resistor. If you have the same resistor lying around, you can use four of these - Put two resitors in parallel. Add to this in series another two resitors in parallel- the value will remain same but the wattage handling will become four times.

Answer (score 0):

I have two 330 ohm 1W resistors in my garage door opener control board .. they get so hot the PCB in the area is discolored.  I jacked then up an inch but the damage was already done on the SMT components.  Replacing the damaged component and replaced the 330 ohm resistors with 5 W rating ones and keeping them one inch above the PCB just to be safe.